# Binding to Media Element,

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I am trying to bind to a media element and all my tries failed,
Code behind :-

```
    private void myg_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string str = ((EgyGuide.Models.Arabic)e.ClickedItem).Sound;
        MediaElement m1 = new MediaElement();
        m1.Source = new System.Uri("ms-appx:///" + str);
        m1.Play();
    }
```

XAML:-

```
                <GridView x:Name="myg"
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                      ItemClick="myg_ItemClick">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding English}"
                                           FontSize="22" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Arabia}"
                                           FontSize="22" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
```

When i made the source directly to my XAML it was working but now when i used this code behind it doesn't work anymore, sound doesnt play at all.
Any help getting this to work please?
Thanks

Comment: First, please put code in code blocks, *not* images (for example, your first one is very hard to read). Second, what error are you getting? "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.

Comment: I am not getting errors the binding doesn't work at all , no sound plays.
images removed.

Comment: Okay, but do you get any `System.Data` exceptions? Bindings very *rarely* fail silently.

Comment: No at all, But i believe it might be something to do with URI?
Because when i created another media element in xaml and then in my code behind when assigned the media element source which i've created with the source of the current one the sound of the media element played successfully . :(

Comment: It certainly could be. Constructing Source Uri's is much more complicated in code-behind than XAML. Should be possible though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. First, `MediaElement` won't play if it isn't in the XAML tree - you need to add it. Second, you shouldn't immediatelly call `Play`, but instead you should wait for the `MediaOpened` event to be raised. Something like this:

Code:

```
MediaElement me;

private void StartButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  me = new MediaElement();

  // Register for critical events. CurrentStateChanged is also useful
  me.MediaOpened += MediaElementMediaOpened;
  me.MediaFailed += MediaElementMediaFailed;

  // Start opening the file
  me.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/WestEndGirls.wma");

  // Add to the XAML tree (assumes a Panel with the name "Root")
  Root.Children.Add(me);
}

// Errors will be reported here
void MediaElementMediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(e.ErrorMessage);
}

// Only once the media has been opened can you play it
void MediaElementMediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  me.Play();
}
```

XAML:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Root">
  <Button Content="Start" Click="StartButtonClicked" />
</StackPanel>
```